# How to fix my SQL Group By issue?

Tags: 8, database

I have a problem with MySql request on Drupal 8.
I want to translate this request to Drupal:

```
SELECT x.camp AS camp, x.code AS espece, y.des AS designation, x.pf AS pf,
ROUND( SUM( x.pn - x.qte ) , 3 ) AS qte
FROM apport.apport x, apport.cereale y, apport.operation z
WHERE x.code = y.code
AND x.ope = z.code
GROUP BY x.camp, x.code
ORDER BY x.camp, x.code
```

This request works on PhpMyAdmin.

So, I do this:

```
    $query = $db->select('apport.apport','x');
    $query->join('apport.cereale','y', 'x.code = y.code');
    $query->join('apport.operation','z', 'x.ope = z.code');

    $query->fields('x', array('camp', 'code' ,'pf'));
    $query->fields('y', array('des'));

    $query->addExpression('ROUND(SUM(x.pn-x.qte),3)','qte');
    $query->groupBy('x.camp')->groupBy('x.code');
    $query->orderBy('x.camp','ASC')->orderBy('x.code','ASC');

    $result = $query->execute();

    $tableau = array();

    foreach ($result as $record) {
        $row['camp'] = $record->camp;
        $row['code'] = $record->code;
        $row['des'] = $record->des;
        $row['pf'] = $record->pf;
        $row['qte'] = $record->qte;

        $tableau[] = $row;

        print_r($tableau);
    }
```

But it doesn't work. The problem comes probably from here:

```
    $query->addExpression('ROUND(SUM(x.pn-x.qte),3)','qte');
    $query->groupBy('x.camp')->groupBy('x.code');
```

Because when I comment the above two lines, I do get a result.

Any help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Drupal use "Full_ group_by" so that why you need to Group all your fields.

If you want disable it and group only on one field, you have to update setting.php

Add this :

```
$databases['default']['default'] ['init_commands'] = [
'sql_mode' => "SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER'",
];
```

Comment: Is this a good approach? I mean by this change may some other feature breaks, is there any other way to set it on a connection?

Comment: Personally, i got no problem until now

Comment: I use this why instead of groupBy, `$query->execute()->fetchAllAssoc('link', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` , In my case I needed to groupBy link that `fetchAllAssoc` do it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution !

You need to group by all arrays

```
    $query = $db->select('apport.apport','x');
    $query->join('apport.cereale','y', 'x.code = y.code');

    $query->fields('x', array('camp', 'code'));
    $query->fields('y', array('des'));

    $query->addExpression('ROUND(SUM(x.pn-x.qte),3)','qte');
    $query->groupBy('x.code')->groupBy('x.camp')->groupBy('y.des');
    $query->orderBy('camp','ASC')->orderBy('code','ASC');
```

I have deleted 'pf' because i didn't want to group by this and the table 'operation' because it was useless

bye :)